# How can I find a prime that satisfies these two congruences?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Hi I was solving a question and now I'm stuck at this part .

$-6x\equiv 16 \pmod p $

$2x\equiv 1 \pmod p $

where $p$ is a prime number.

I need to find all prime numbers that satisfy these congruences.

I think that Chinese remainder theorem might help somehow but I don't see it.

Comment: Generally the Chinese remainder theorem would be applicable when you have multiple bases. Here you only have base $p$.

Comment: @Joffan Modulus, not base, is far more common in elementary number theory.

Comment: @Joffan Our of curiosity, where did you learn the term "base" for the  modulus?

Comment: @BillDubuque No idea really - I guess I was just wrong.

Comment: @Joffan It might be due to a language translation error, or some other mistake that has been propagated on the web. The only mention I saw in the first few pages of a Google search was on a [Tutors in China site](http://www.tutorsinchina.com/dictionary%20/congruence-modulo-n/) which defines "congruence modulo n" as  "Arithmetics where 2 quantities differing by a multiple of the chosen base n are considered the same..." I don't recall ever seeing "base" used before.

Comment: @Joffan Another possibility is that some authors have borrowed ideal language, where generators of an ideal are referred to as bases (a generalization of vector space terminology to modules).

Answer (score 2):

$16+6x = k_1p$

$2x =  1 + k_2p$ =>

$16 = -3 + (k_1 - 3k_2)p$

=> $p|19$

Comment: Thank you but please , give a hint next time :C

Answer (score 2):

*Eliminate* $\,x,\ $ e.g. $\ {\rm mod}\ p\!:\,\ 16 \equiv -3(\color{#c00}{2x})\equiv -3(\color{#c00}{\bf 1})\,\Rightarrow\, 16\!+\!3\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\,p\mid 19$

Answer (score 1):

We are given the two congruences:
$$-6x\equiv 16\ (\mathrm{mod}\ p)\qquad(*)$$
$$2x\equiv 1\ (\mathrm{mod}\ p)\qquad(**)$$
We multiply $(**)$ by $3$ and add the resulting to $(*)$, to get
$$0\equiv 19\ (\mathrm{mod}\ p)$$
This is possible only when $p=19$ or $p$ is a factor of $19$, which is not possible. Hence, the only value of $p$ satisfying the congruences is $19$.

If this doesn't seem good to you, then we have
$$16\equiv-6x\equiv -3(2x)\equiv-3 (\mathrm{mod}\ p)$$
$$\implies0\equiv19\ (\mathrm{mod}\ p)$$
which is the same as above.

Hope it helps :)